# Modify resource file at runtime, get compiler error CS0042

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In Asp.net project, I want to Update Resource file at runtime,
but I found that in some cases, there will be errors.

There are five language resource files for each function. If I want to update A.cshtml resource file.

My implementation steps are as follows:

(It must be guaranteed that when someone is using this page, they can also edit the resource file for this page)

1. Execute project in my computer
2. Open A.cshtml in Chrome (already switched to the corresponding language)
3. Update A.resx file content
4. Refresh A.cshtml in Chrome
5. Get compiler error CS0042

> Compile Error Description: Resource compilation could not be completed
>   (error occurred on service request). Please review the specific error
>   details below and modify your source code as appropriate.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0042: Create debug information file
>   'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\9a4f0e64\5b92b0fc\zh-CN\App_GlobalResources.ytq0hlfh.resources.
>   Unexpected error occurred while PDB' --
>   'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\9a4f0e64\5b92b0fc\zh-CN\App_GlobalResources.ytq0hlfh.resources.pdb:
>   The program cannot access the file because the file is being used by
>   another program.

The above error only occurs when I am modifying a language resource file other than zh-TW.

```
A.resx (zh-TW) > OK
A.zh-CN.resx > error
A.en-US.resx > error
A.th-TH.resx > error
A.ja-JP.resx > error
```

Comment: To me this looks like a design error (aka [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)). If you want the users to edit strings that are being displayed on a page, put these strings into a database.

Comment: The regulations must be use resource file.